# Getting TIMESTAMP error while using below query on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

```
select timestamp_diff(TIMESTAMP "d.login_time",TIMESTAMP "b.logout_time",HOUR) from (
    select distinct a.id, TIMESTAMP("a.action_time") as logout_time
from TMP_DB a
)b
left join
(
select distinct c.actor_id, TIMESTAMP("c.action_time") as login_time
from TMP_DB c
)d
on b.id = d.id
```

I have Time format like "2021-03-16 13:30:36"

Comment: Take a look at the following link to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try removing quotes around `a.action_time` and `c.action_time`

This one returned `9.3.2` for me:

```
select json_extract_scalar(json_extract_scalar(REPLACE(REPLACE(r'{"userPlatformEnum":"APP","deviceDetails":"{\”userPlatformEnum\”:\”APP\”,\”dbClientName\”:\”xxxxxxx\”,\”appVersion\":\"9.3.2\",\"dbClientId\”:\”xxxxx\”,\”latitude\":\"0.0\",\"ip\”:\”xxxxx\”,\”language\":\"en\",\"locale\":\"en-IN\”,\"deviceId\”:\”xxxxxx\”,\”deviceName\”:\”xxxxx\”,\”createdAt\":\"Apr 20, 2020 09:57:28 PM\",\"updatedAt\":\"Apr 20, 2020 09:57:28 PM\}","clientId”:”xxxxx”,”verifiedVia”:”xxxx”,”userAgent":"okhttp/3.12.2","externalClientId”:”xxxxx”,”userNameUsed”:”xxxxx”}', '\\"', '\''), '\\”', '\''), '$.deviceDetails'), '$.appVersion')
```

Comment: Not able to extract json value available with backslash in google BigQuery

data format available in Db data= Details":"{"Platfo":"APP\”,\”user\”:\”xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx\”,\”appVersion\”:\”1.3.1\”}

Need to extract appVersion valuw i.e 1.3.1

Im using below logic for extraction

select json_extract(data, '$.appVersion') AS AppVersion

Comment: Try this: `select json_extract(REPLACE(r'{"Details":{"Platfo":"APP\",\"user\":\"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx\",\"appVersion\":\"1.3.1\"}}', '\\', ''), '$.Details.appVersion')`

Comment: Its still not working, getting blank result

Comment: for me it returns `"1.3.1"` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Actually below my original data, and available in "Data" column. here i need to extract appVersion value.
{"userPlatformEnum":"APP","deviceDetails":"{\"userPlatformEnum\":\"APP\",\"dbClientName\”:\”xxxxxxx\”,\”appVersion\":\"9.3.2\",\"dbClientId\”:\”xxxxx\”,\”latitude\":\"0.0\",\"ip\”:\”xxxxx\”,\”language\":\"en\",\"locale\":\"en-IN\",\"deviceId\”:\”xxxxxx\”,\”deviceName\”:\”xxxxx\”,\”createdAt\":\"Apr 20, 2020 09:57:28 PM\",\"updatedAt\":\"Apr 20, 2020 09:57:28 PM\"}","clientId”:”xxxxx”,”verifiedVia”:”xxxx”,”userAgent":"okhttp/3.12.2","externalClientId”:”xxxxx”,”userNameUsed”:”xxxxx”}